# Creating synonym filter programmatically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, hibernate-search

I am struggling with the creation of a [SynonymFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) that I try to create programmatically. How are you supposed to tell the filter where the synonym list is?

I am using Hibernate Search, but I don't want to use the `@AnalyzerDef` annotation.
All I can do is pass a synonym map?

```
private class AllAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    private SynonymFilterFactory synonymFilterFactory = new SynonymFilterFactory();

    public AllAnalyzer() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String filePath = classLoader.getResource("synonyms.txt").getFile();
        HashMap<String, String> stringStringHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        stringStringHashMap.put("synonyms", filePath);
        stringStringHashMap.put("format", "solr");
        stringStringHashMap.put("ignoreCase", "false");
        stringStringHashMap.put("expand", "true");
        stringStringHashMap.put("luceneMatchVersion", Version.LUCENE_36.name());
        synonymFilterFactory.init(stringStringHashMap);
    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        TokenStream result = null;
        result = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);
        result = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, result);
        result = synonymFilterFactory.create(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unable to get it to work. When I debug it says that the map is null and I get a NPE. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to pass a `SynonymMap` to the SynonymFilter.

Sounds like you want to populate it from a file, so you'll likely want to use [`SolrSynonymParser`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SolrSynonymParser.html) to generate it.  Along the lines of:

```
SolrSynonymParser parser = new SolrSynonymParser(true, false, analyzer);
Reader synonymFileReader = new FileRader(new File(path));
parser.add(synonymFileReader);
SynonymMap map = parser.build(); // SolrSynonymParser extends SynonymMap.Builder
```

Comment: How are you supposed to know that? No documentation at all?

Comment: If your using hibernate search,  you are generally expected to use the annotations for that.  For solr,  similar story, the args to the SynonymFilterFactory would be used.

Comment: Could you give an example of SynonymFilterFactory? I am currently trying to create a custom analyzer programatically. I need to add the synonymfilter inside the analyzer class. How would you do that?

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/analysis/SynonymFilterFactory.html

Comment: I already gave you that.  If, for whatever reason, you would rather use the factory that is designed to take in args specified in an xml configuration, then go to it.  Everything you need is right there in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, so the args parameter uses the key from the XML? But I struggle with how I can create this filter inside an analyzer subclass. Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I would appriciate an example with an subclass of an analyzer that use a synonym filter. I get exceptions.

Comment: What should be there as an analyzer in following line ?SolrSynonymParser parser = new SolrSynonymParser(true, false, analyzer);